# Can I access the private key of solana account (via phantom) to encrypt data?

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, solana, diffie-hellman

As far as I know, every account is represented by a public/private key. The public key can be accessed anytime and the private key is (obviously) never shown.

Is there however a way to access the private key of Solana (via phantom) so data can be encrypted and then saved to the blockchain?

The idea is: two addresses interact and via [Diffie Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) use the combined key to encrypt the message/content so that only these two can read the message

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the @solana/wallet-adapter, the wallet interface provides a `signMessage` function: https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/469edb5dd45231d397751b0268c86dffd6ed730a/packages/core/react/src/useWallet.ts#L37 which just encrypts any byte array that you pass into it.  See the interface definition at https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/a5b1ebd70ae9753d188fec60e95e252402f3f371/packages/core/base/src/signer.ts#L55

With that, you don't get access to the private key, but you can sign any arbitrary message, which should be enough.  If it isn't, please feel free to create an issue and suggest an addition to the interface.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So I am aware of this and implemented it here: https://johnb8005.github.io/web3/phantom/ - this works great. However I really am looking for a way to store encrypted data to the blockchain (else anybody can read the content of what's saved in the blockchain)

Comment: in my opinion, it would be quite "elegant" to leverage the private key and do key exchange either with yourself or another party

Comment: are you aware of a discord where I could discuss with other people?

Comment: You can certainly store that encrypted data! In that case, you'll need an on-chain program to handle storage, and some client to retrieve / decrypt.

Feel free to join the Solana Tech Discord https://discord.gg/solana or the Anchor Discord (for building on-chain programs) https://discord.gg/qhud7BWT

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access any private key. If you could it would not be called a private key. Unless private key owner explicitly publishes it.

You can create a keypair for the account and then save this keypair. For example create a new file `keypairGenerator.js` and add this:

```
const fs=require('fs')
const anchor=require("@project-serum/anchor")
const account=anchor.web3.Keypair.generate()
fs.writeFileSync('./keypair.json',JSON.stringify(account))
```

this will write the keypair to `keypair.json` file and it will look like this:

```
{"_keypair":{
"publicKey":{"0":129,"1":88,"2":146,"3":38,"4":224,"5":124,"6":88,"7":26,"8":244,"9":238,"10":238,"11":61,"12":140,"13":33,"14":116,"15":74,"16":161,"17":184,"18":56,"19":194,"20":189,"21":151,"22":82,"23":29,"24":226,"25":204,"26":94,"27":142,"28":1,"29":130,"30":5,"31":222},
"secretKey":{"0":220,"1":93,"2":217,"3":140,"4":50,"5":48,"6":225,"7":236,"8":144,"9":88,"10":167,"11":3,"12":60,"13":179,"14":31,"15":102,"16":161,"17":190,"18":91,"19":173,"20":89,"21":19,"22":159,"23":203,"24":66,"25":188,"26":210,"27":50,"28":159,"29":16,"30":28,"31":234,"32":129,"33":88,"34":146,"35":28,"36":224,"37":144,"38":88,"39":26,"40":244,"41":238,"42":238,"43":61,"44":140,"45":33,"46":116,"47":74,"48":161,"49":184,"50":56,"51":194,"52":189,"53":151,"54":82,"55":29,"56":226,"57":204,"58":93,"59":132,"60":1,"61":130,"62":5,"63":222}}}
```

in your project, assuming written in javascript:

```
 import keypair from './keypair.json'

// Object.values will get the values of keypair._keypair.secretKey object into array
const keypairArray=Object.values(keypair._keypair.secretKey)
const secret=new Uint8Array(keypairArray)
const account=web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secret)
```